# How to control HTML table column widths?

Tags: html, html-table, column-width

I'm working on an HTML page that displays a table of data (using the `<table>` element). I'm currently setting the CSS width of each column to a percentage, with the NAME column at 60% because it can be the largest. Here's an actual screenshot:

[image: current]

What I'd really like to do is somehow "anchor" the DATE column to the right of the NAME column, creating some nice white space between it and the COPY, DOWNLOAD, and SHARE columns. Here's a doctored screenshot:

[image: desired]

However, I can't just give the DATE column a large percentage, because I want it to decrease in size if the NAME happens to be longer. Here's another doctored screenshot. If the name is longer, then the NAME column should increase in width to accommodate, and the DATE column should decrease in width:

[image: even better]

Is there some way to accomplish what I want via CSS, and without moving away from a `<table>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "td" to this:

```
tr td.name-column {
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

(Where name-column is the class added to the "td" element)

You can also try adding some padding to give it some room